# How to calculate pitch, roll and yaw from affine transformation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to rotate an image based on the rotation angle of pitch, roll, and yaw. `R = rotx(theta1)*roty(theta2)*rotz(theta3)`, the rotation matrix R is formed by the affine transform within rotation as below following.

```
R_2d = [R(1,1)  R(1,2)  0;
        R(2,1)  R(2,2)  0;
         0        0     1];

tform = affine2d(R_2d);
outputImage = imwarp(img,tform, 'OutputView', imref2d(size(img)));
```

The R rotation matrix could be set on the affine transformation of rotation even I force to strip the values of z-axis. So that I could not retrieve angle on the pitch, roll, and yaw from R_2d causing by `R_2d(3,1)=0`, `R_2d(3,2)=0`, and `R_2d(3,3) = 1`

```
yaw = rad2deg(atan2(R_2d(2,1),R_2d(1,1)))
pitch = rad2deg(atan2(-R_2d(3,1),sqrt(R_2d(3,2)^2+R_2d(3,3)^2)))
roll = rad2deg(atan2(R_2d(3,2),R_2d(3,3)))
```

I am not realized how to retrieve it from R_2d to 3d?

In my addition, I am also trying to use the original image and the transformed image to get tform of affine.

```
tformd = fitgeotrans(movingPoints,fixedPoints,'affine')
```

but the estimation of tformd is not similar to tform. does the tformd include on rotation, scaling, shearing, and translation? how should I do it?

Thank you.